# Can a viscous and a compressible fluid flow steadily?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity

I read that an ideal fluid is the incomprehensible non-viscous one, so my question is can a fluid that is not ideal flow steadily?

Comment: I have always thought that fluid flow was mostly incomprehensible too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Definition of an ideal fluid.**

Ideal fluid is usually defined as a fluid with zero viscosity and heat conductivity, resulting in no entropy production wherever differential equations hold.

The latter sentence is necessary, since compressible inviscid, non-conductive fluids may experience shocks that are usually modeled as discontinuities in non-viscous fluids and are sources of entropy production.

**Steady flows of non ideal fluids.**

Flows with very low characteristic Reynolds number may "flow steadily", if I understand what you mean. Namely, at very low Reynolds number, steady laminar flows of viscous fluids exist, like the Newton, Poiseuille or Couettw flows that can be found analytically as exact solutions of Navier-Stokes equations.